# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function update_plugin_points_on_mycred_award(), 3 passed

Tags: php, wordpress

sorry if i'm not posting at the right place and please pardon my English.

I have a custom coded plugin that gives user point, and the their point on 'points' column on my database 'wallets' table.

Now i installed mycred plugin, and i want when users earn point from mycred plugin, the earned mycred point should be added to the custom plugin 'points' on the database.

I have the snippet code below;

```
// Hook into myCRED points update event
add_action('mycred_add', 'update_plugin_points_on_mycred_award', 10, 4);

function update_plugin_points_on_mycred_award($new_balance, $amount, $type, $data) {
    // Check if the points update is from a myCRED task
    if ($type === 'view_content') {
        // Get current user ID
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if ($user_id) {
            // Update your plugin's points database with the new balance
            update_user_points_in_plugin($user_id, $new_balance);
        }
    }
}

// Function to update points in your plugin's database
function update_user_points_in_plugin($user_id, $points) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wallets';
    $wpdb->update(
        $table_name,
        array('points' => $points),
        array('user_id' => $user_id),
        array('%d'),
        array('%d')
    );
}
```

Now when users clicks on a post to read, the error below will appear

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function update_plugin_points_on_mycred_award(),
  3 passed in /home/credxmud/job.capitalholdinvestment.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324 
  and exactly 4 expected in /home/credxmud/job.capitalholdinvestment.com/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(582) : eval()'d code:4
Stack trace: 
 #0 /home/credxmud/job.capitalholdinvestment.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): update_plugin_points_on_mycred_award(true, Array, Object(myCRED_Settings))
 #1 /home/credxmud/job.capitalholdinvestment.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters(true, Array)
 #2 /home/credxmud/job.capitalholdinvestment.com/wp-content/plugins/mycred/includes/mycred-functions.php(1497): apply_filters('mycred_add', true, Array, Object(myCRED_Settings))
 #3 /home/credxmud/job.capitalholdinvestment.com/wp-content/plugins/mycred/includes/hooks/mycred-hook-view-content.php(97): myCRED_Settings->add_creds('view_content', 13, 50, '%plural% for vi...', 72, Array, 'mycred_de
in /home/credxmud/job.capitalholdinvestment.com/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(582) : eval()'d code on line 4
```

Please if anyone can help me. I'm using latest WordPress version and PHP 8.0

I'm expecting that, when user read a post, they'll earn mycred plugin point, and the earned amount will be added to the user 'points' column on the database.

Comment: According to the error, at some point you are calling `apply_filters('mycred_add', true, Array, Object(myCRED_Settings))`, however your signature says there should be four parameters, That said, looking at the signature of your function, it doesn't really look like what you are passing matches this at all. The first parameter is `$new_balance` and you are passing `true` to that. You then pass that value to another function where it is called `$points`, and that seems weird.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think the `apply_filters` method is part of WordPress core, so it's not that the user is passing the wrong parameters, it's that their callback definition doesn't match the parameters the plugin is passing when it runs the hook they've registered.

Comment: @IMSoP, I was just assuming that `mycred_add` is the OP's filter/action, but if it is from a plugin I'd agree. If it is their filter/action, then it is their job to have them both align. If it isn't their filter, then yes, their function is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Right. It's not totally clear, but I think "mycred" is a third-party plugin they're trying to hook into, and the plugin they wrote is separate.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see that now that you've cleaned up the stacktrace, thanks for that!

Comment: This appears to be the documentation for that filter: https://codex.mycred.me/filters/mycred_add-2/ It does indeed document three parameters; they look nothing like the ones you have, so I'm not sure if you were thinking of a different hook, a different plugin, or what...